# Did rospy remapping arguments change in Fuerte?

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-fuerte, remapping, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a weird error with remapping arguments on Fuerte. In my rospy node, I have a line like

```
baud_rate = rospy.param('~baud',4800)
```

so when I'd like to change that on the commandline, I tried

```
rosrun nmea_gps_driver nmea_gps_driver.py _baud:=38400
```

but instead of the parameter being set, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid remapping argument '_baud:=38400'
```

That remapping works just fine in Electric and I don't see anything in the [rosrun](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosrun) or [Fuerte Migration Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration).

In case it matters, I'm working against the latest Fuerte .debs on Ubuntu 11.10.

UPDATE:

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# test.py
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('rospy')
import rospy

rospy.init_node('test_node')

test_param = rospy.get_param('~test', 4800)

print "Param was: %d" % (test_param)
```

If I run this like `python test.py _test:=38400`, I get the error output. See below.

```
$ python test.py _test:=38400
ERROR: Invalid remapping argument '_test:=38400'
Param was: 4800
$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27949/did-rospy-remapping-arguments-change-in-fuerte?/) by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8406 on 2012-02-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was a bug due to some code refacotrintg.  Fixed in r16352.  Will be included in next ros_comm update.

BTW: thanks for the simplified test case, made this quick to fix

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3